# Циклический сдвиг целого в C

Tags: битовые-операции, c

Подскажите,  для unsigned int?

Но как быть с размером типа данных unsigned int? Ведь в стандарте не предусмотрен обязателньый размер его. Скорее всего, это 4 байта, но не обязательно. 
Как действовать тогда?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t rotl(uint32_t n, size_t shift) 
{return (n << shift) | (n >> (32 - shift));}
```

Comment: Здесь нет никакой привязки, uint32_t это беззнаковый целочисленный тип фиксированной гарантированной длины 32 бита из стандарта С99.

Comment: Если вам нужен сдвиг для слов любого размера используйте #define WIDTH sizeof(unsinged int)*CHAR_BIT

Comment: @igumnov, автор же как раз говорит о том, что размер unsigned int

    Скорее всего, это 4 байта, но не обязательно. Как действовать тогда?

Тогда надо вычислить длину `unsigned int` в битах и получим

     #include <limits.h>
     ...
     #define BITLEN(x) (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT)

     ...
     static inline unsigned int usrotl(unsigned int x, unsigned int k) {
       return (x << (k % BITLEN(x))) | (x >> (BITLEN(x) - k % BITLEN(x)));
     }

Comment: Да это более разумный вариант если ТСа не заинтересован в конкретной ширине слова которое он собирается сдвигать.